# How to get response from IPN cryptocurrencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, payment, coinpayments-api

We're trying to receive payment with cryptocurrencies using coinpayment IPN. We are able to create a request and able to do a payment. However, not able to get success or failure response while user come back to the seller side.

Here is how payment request created:

```
public ActionResult IPN()
{                        

    var uri = new UriBuilder("https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php");
    uri.SetQueryParam("cmd", "_pay_auto"); 
    uri.SetQueryParam("merchant", "merchant_key");
    uri.SetQueryParam("allow_extra", "0");
    uri.SetQueryParam("currency", "USD"); 
    uri.SetQueryParam("reset", "1");
    uri.SetQueryParam("success_url", "http://localhost:49725/home/SuccessResponse"); //todo: redirect to confirm success page
    uri.SetQueryParam("key", "wc_order_5b7b84b91a882");
    uri.SetQueryParam("cancel_url", "http://localhost:49725/home/FailiureResponse");
    uri.SetQueryParam("order_id", "36");
    uri.SetQueryParam("invoice", "PREFIX-36");
    uri.SetQueryParam("ipn_url", "http://localhost:49725/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Coinpayments");
    uri.SetQueryParam("first_name", "John");
    uri.SetQueryParam("last_name", "Smith");
    uri.SetQueryParam("email", "a@a.com");
    uri.SetQueryParam("want_shipping", "1");
    uri.SetQueryParam("address1", "228 Park Ave S&address2");
    uri.SetQueryParam("city", "New York");
    uri.SetQueryParam("state", "NY");
    uri.SetQueryParam("zip", "10003-1502");
    uri.SetQueryParam("country", "US");
    uri.SetQueryParam("item_name", "Order 33");
    uri.SetQueryParam("quantity", "1");
    uri.SetQueryParam("amountf", "100.00000000");
    uri.SetQueryParam("shippingf", "0.00000000");            

    return Redirect(uri.ToString());
}
```

This will be redirected to the coinpayment site, once payment done, it is showing the following screen.

[image]

And trying to get data when user click on back to seller's site, I have tried to get data using `Request.Form`, but not getting any value in form.

The same thing, working with [this woocommerce code](https://pastebin.com/R7DPytqk), but I have no idea of PHP and how they are dealing with it.

Any thought to get IPN response?

Note: there is no development documentation or sample code available for IPN in .NET

**Edit**
I'm trying to get value from IPN success

```
Public ActionResult SuccessResponse()
{
    var ipn_version = Request.Form["ipn_version"];
    var ipn_id = Request.Form["ipn_id"];
    var ipn_mode = Request.Form["ipn_mode"];
    var merchant = Request.Form["merchant"];
    var txn_id = Request.Form["txn_id"];
    var status = Request.Form["status"];

    return Content(status);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As updated answer stated by @Gillsoft AB, you should need to use valid IPN URL from the code end. Also webhook would not work with localhost. thus, you should listen the request with live server.

Simplest way to check webhook response is to use online tool such as [Webhook Tester](https://webhook.site/), it will provide an URL which you have to set as your IPN URL, whenever server will sends the data, you can simply see it to the web. To check that, create one URL and set as your IPN URL as below:

```
 uri.SetQueryParam("ipn_url", "https://webhook.site/#/457f5c55-c9ce-4db4-8f57-20194c17d0ae");
```

After that run the payment cycle from local machine, payment server will sends notification to that IPN URL.

Make sure you understood it right! `success_url` and `cancel_url` are for user redirection, you will not get any response code over there, inspection of `seller's store` URL give your exact same URL that you have been passing though, so it is recommended to use unique URLs for each order(i.e add order id at last to the URL) which will give you an idea which order payment has been done or canceled.

```
http://localhost:49725/home/SuccessResponse?orderid=123
```

In order to test your local code, add following changes and deployed it to server.

1) Add one new method which will listen IPN response

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult IPNHandler()
{
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

    //TODO: print string request 

    //nothing should be rendered to visitor
    return Content(""); 
}
```

2) Pass IPN URL while creating a request:

```
public ActionResult IPN()
{                        
    var uri = new UriBuilder("https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php");
    ...
    ..
    uri.SetQueryParam("success_url", "http://localhost:49725/home/SuccessResponse"); 
    uri.SetQueryParam("cancel_url", "http://localhost:49725/home/FailiureResponse");    
    uri.SetQueryParam("ipn_url", "http://localhost:49725/home/IPNHandler");
    ....
    ..
    return Redirect(uri.ToString());
}
```

You will get all status code responses in `IPNHandler` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Webhook tester you linked saved the day for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use localhost for a IPN callback. You must use a public domain name.

As an example I would change the following parameters:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder("https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php"); 
uri.SetQueryParam("success_url", "http://kugugshivom-001-site1.atempurl.com/Home/SuccessResponse");
uri.SetQueryParam("cancel_url", "http://kugugshivom-001-site1.atempurl.com/Home/FailiureResponse");
uri.SetQueryParam("ipn_url", "http://kugugshivom-001-site1.atempurl.com/Home/CoinPaymentsIPN"); // Public ActionResult CoinPaymentsIPN()
```

Since you are creating your own gateway you also need to implement it properly as described in the documentation at [CoinPayments API](https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc) and [Instant Payment Notifications (IPN)](https://www.coinpayments.net/merchant-tools-ipn).

I have tested your *success_url* endpoint, and got **status code: 100** (when entering status:100). I see you use form-data, but I don't know if that's on purpose / required.

**Postman** POST `http://kugugshivom-001-site1.atempurl.com/Home/SuccessResponse`
In *Body* tab form-data is selected with *Bulk Edit* values:

```
ipn_version:1.0
ipn_type:api
ipn_mode:hmac
ipn_id:your_ipn_id
merchant:your_merchant_id
txn_id:your_transaction_id
status:100
```

Comment: Yup, pretty much this. Localhost is a relative url, from their end it probably tries to call the url they entered, but there is no response. For testing, the OP could expose the https port, host the app through IIS, and then port forward the local ip through their router to accomplish this though.

Comment: `SuccessResponse` method getting called when user clicks on back to seller;s store, then also do I need to host my app?

Comment: Okay, will give a try

Comment: Thanks@GillsoftAB, but seems like they aren't provide support for .net

Comment: yes @GillsoftAB, I think [smarterasp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net/) would work, let me try though. Here the question is do need to use `https` instead? and as you made change in `ipn_url`, which method will be called on success `SuccessResponse` or else?

Comment: Tried with publishing app, running at http://kugugshivom-001-site1.atempurl.com/ and trying to get response showed in updated question, but no luck

Comment: @GillsoftAB No luck though!

Comment: @TravisJ: Could you suggest me anything that I can try and check

Comment: @HinaKhuman - Have you tried using a breakpoint at SuccessResponse to see if it is being requested? Or even just tracking all requests to see if *something* is being requested?

Comment: @TravisJ: I cannot put a break point as I'm checking with deployed app. With localhost, yes break point is getting hit, but the issue is not able to retrieve data anyway

Comment: I updated my answer, I have tested it so I know it works.